# Prestashop displayPaymentReturn hook url

Tags: module, hook, prestashop, payment

I am new as Prestashop developer and I am trying to create a PaymentModule. I have got to show my payment method but I can not proceed with purchase because I do not know very well hot it works.

Does anyone know where I should redirect to run my hoodDisplayPaymentReturn method?

I will be very happy if someone explain me the complete navigation map to make a purchase.

Anyway, where can I find a relation between hooks and pages?

Answer (score 2):

To develop a payment module you should use 2 main hooks: `payment` and `paymentReturn`.

In `payment` hook you must display your payment option with the specific information. Check `bankwire` module to see a working example.
In `paymentReturn` you should show the payment confirmation (or error) information.

When a user click on your payment option link (displayed in `payment` hook) you should do some validation and processing. After a payment is done (successfully or not) you must call to your module function `validateOrder` (this is a function of `PaymentModule` parent class of your module). After that you should be redirected to a controller that will execute `paymentReturn` hook.

That is the basic process. I strongly recommend you that check bankwire and other payment modules to understand better how to do your own payment module, because is not an easy task for beginner.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

when I have a new module for the payment I rely on the simplest provided by PrestaShop: bankwire.

inside you can find 3 hooks.

**HookPayment:**

```
public function hookPayment($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;
    if (!$this->checkCurrency($params['cart']))
        return;

    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'this_path' => $this->_path,
        'this_path_bw' => $this->_path,
        'this_path_ssl' => Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/'
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment.tpl');
}
```

**hookDisplayPaymentEU:**

```
public function hookDisplayPaymentEU($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    if (!$this->checkCurrency($params['cart']))
        return;

    $payment_options = array(
        'cta_text' => $this->l('Pay by Bank Wire'),
        'logo' => Media::getMediaPath(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/bankwire.jpg'),
        'action' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'validation', array(), true)
    );

    return $payment_options;
}
```

**hookPaymentReturn:**

```
public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    $state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();
    if (in_array($state, array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_BANKWIRE'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'))))
    {
        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'bankwireDetails' => Tools::nl2br($this->details),
            'bankwireAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
            'bankwireOwner' => $this->owner,
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id
        ));
        if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
            $this->smarty->assign('reference', $params['objOrder']->reference);
    }
    else
        $this->smarty->assign('status', 'failed');
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment_return.tpl');
}
```